# Mongoose script to seed database hangs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following script:

```js
const db = require('../db')
const User = require('../models/user')

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'))

const main = async () => {
    const users = [
        new User({ name: 'Benny', age: 28, status: 'active' }),
        new User({ name: 'Claire', age: 28, status: 'active' })
    ]
    const newUsers = async () => {
        await users.forEach(async user => await user.save())
    }
    await newUsers()
    console.log("Created users!")
}

const run = async () => {
        await main()
        process.exit(0)
}

run()
```

For some reason `process.exit()` executes before `main()` resolves and therefore I get no users created.

If I remove `process.exit()` my script works but hangs.

How do I get my script to work and exit once done executing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution - would love some feedback on improving it!

```js
const db = require('../db')
const User = require('../models/user')

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'))

const main = async () => {
    const users = [
        { name: 'Benny', age: 28, status: 'active' },
        { name: 'Claire', age: 28, status: 'active' }
    ]

    await User.insertMany(users)
    console.log("Created users!")
}

const run = async () => {
    await main()
    db.close()
}

run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Awaiting `users.forEach()` doesn't do anything because `forEach` doesn't have a return value, so there's nothing to await. It's likely iterating through the entire list and then exiting immediately, which then returns from `main` and calls `process.exit()` before the `.save()`s have a chance to execute.

What you can do, however, is wait for all the promises to finish by using `Promise.all()`. This will require you to map each user creation into a Promise, but that's what your `User.save` function is doing anyway, it's returning a Promise. Here's an example of how you can do that:

```js
function save(user) {
  // do something async here
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(`${user.name} Saved!`);
      resolve()
    }, 1500);
  });
}

const main = async () => {
    const users = [
        { name: 'Benny', age: 28, status: 'active' },
        { name: 'Claire', age: 28, status: 'active' }
    ]
    // map async processes into an array of promises
    const newUsers = users.map(user => save(user));
    // await the resolution of all promises, then proceeed
    await Promise.all(newUsers);
    console.log("Created users!")
}

const run = async () => {
  await main()
  console.log("done")
}

run()
```

The distinct benefit of doing it this way is that the database calls will happen in parallel, which will make your seeding process much faster. Conceptually, what you were trying to do would have waited for each database call to finish before starting the next one (aka running serially). If you need them to execute in order, then that's a good thing, but it doesn't seem like your use-case requires that.

Answer (score 0):

Co-worker of mine proposed this solution:

```js
const db = require('../db')
const User = require('../models/user')

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'))

const main = async () => {
    const users = [
        new User({ name: 'Benny', age: 28, status: 'active' }),
        new User({ name: 'Claire', age: 28, status: 'active' })
    ]
    const newUsers = async () => {
        await users.reduce(async (promise, user) => {
            await user.save()
            return promise
        }, Promise.resolve())
    }
    await newUsers()
    console.log("Created users!")
}

const run = async () => {
        await main()
        process.exit()
}

run()
```

Comment: Are you just dying to use the `async/await` keywords? I don't understand this amount of jumping through hoops to make this work how you want it.

Comment: Sorry no not at all, in the above code where are the async calls useless? i'm still learning how to use async/await appropriately.

Comment: They're not necessarily useless, it's just a lot of unnecessary work just to make a list of promises to await. Really the only difference between `await` and `Promise.then()` is using a callback verses getting the return value pseudo-synchronously. `async/await` doesn't work without promises, so trying to use async/await and completely avoid the Promise API doesn't really make sense. My suggestion is to use the one that is most appropriate for the job.